# browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() does not delete all cookies

Tags: protractor

In my application if jsessionid is not deleted user remains logged in. only if jsession id is cleared user will be logged out. 
Also jsessionid cookie is not stored under Browser->Application->Cookies/Local Storage/Session Storage.

I have tried following which is not deleting jsessionid `browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
 browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
 browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

how to delete jsessionid cookies in protractor? will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Did you found any solution on this?

Comment: No Solution, but a workaround calling a URL in my test which is written by dev team and it clears the Jsessions, cookies etc. this is called Logout URL, which basically loges out currently logged in user and deletes Cookies/Session/Local storage.